# High memory consumption of ASP.NET Core MVC vs previous ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

We were curious how our new ASP.NET Core MVC web application might perform against our current ASP.NET MVC application. While throughput may be good (nothing we were concerned about in our previous application), the following made us question our effort:

Higher startup time (not serious but notable)
3-5 times more memory consumption

Now the latter made us really worry because this is a huge difference. Nowhere on the internet could I find comments on this. The opposite is true: on most announcements it was stated that ASP.NET Core would require less memory then the previous version. So we checked the default ASP.NET Core MVC template (maybe we made a serious mistake somewhere). But even the default ASP.NET Core MVC template took about 100 MB memory. Compared to about 20 MB memory of the previous ASP.NET MVC template, this is an increase by factor 5.

So maybe someone can answer these questions:

Why is this?
Are there any solutions to mitigate this problem?
Will there be a solution for this in near future?
Why can’t I find anyone complaining about this?

Comment: how to tell why this is happening without seeing the code?

Comment: Both 20 MB and 100 MB of memory is nothing (yes, it's 2017). Does this prove to be a problem? Is the increase equal between both versions, or does Core actually remain on 100 MB with more incoming requests while MVC 5 increases with 20 MB per request?

Comment: "Does this prove to be a problem?" - Yes it does, if your scaling strategy of a product is constrained by given architecture and politics and you have to run many instances of the same service. In such hypothetical case this would mean a factor 5 increase of expensive hardware resources.

Comment: how did you even measure this? im sure that ASP.NET is more than 100MB out of the box. but interested as to where you pulled the values from.